# How can I get a limit arrow without modifying the current line's height?

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I'm using `$f(x)\xrightarrow[x\to\infty] l$` to denote that a function tends to a certain value.  However, this stretches the current line vertically. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: I should add this is a problem when I use it along text, not as a stand-alone equation.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you meant to say `$f(x)  \xrightarrow{x\to\infty} l$` which produces better results.

Otherwise, `\scriptstyle` does what is asked for, but not sure you'll like the results:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
I'm using $f(x)  \scriptstyle \xrightarrow[x\to\infty] l$ to denote that a function tends to a certain value. However, this stretches the current line vertically. Is there any way to fix this?
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a bad hack, but it seems to work:

```
\newcommand{\tendsto}[1]{%
  \xrightarrow{\smash{\raisebox{-2ex}{$\scriptstyle#1$}}}}

$f(x)\tendsto{x\to\infty}l$
```

You may have to adjust the "2ex" if the symbols used below the arrow are higher.